# Comparison test in improper integrals

Tags: real-analysis

Assume you have two functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ such that $f= \text{o}(g)$. I know that if $f$ is non-negative on an interval $J$, then the convergence of $\int_J g(x)dx$ implies the convergence of $\int_J f(x) dx$. But what is the case if $f$ is negative? I could not find a counterexample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not true as stated.  For example, $1/x^3 = o(1/(x+1)^2)$ **as $x \to \infty$**, but $\int_0^\infty 1/x^3\; dx$ diverges while $\int_0^\infty 1/(x+1)^2\; dx$ converges. Of course here the divergence happens as $x \to 0$, not as $x \to \infty$.

A correct statement is: if $f$ and $g$ are bounded on $(0, \infty)$, $g \ge 0$, $\int_0^\infty g(x)\; dx$ converges, and $f(x) = o(g(x))$ as $x \to \infty$,
then $\int_0^\infty f(x) \; dx$ converges.

On the other hand, if $f$ and $g$ are bounded on $(0,\infty)$, $\int_0^\infty g(x)\; dx$ converges,
and $f(x) = o(|g(x)|)$, then it is possible for 
$\int_0^\infty f(x)\; dx$ to diverge, even if $f \ge 0$.  The crucial point is not whether $f \ge 0$, rather whether $g \ge 0$.